# react-hook-form and useState (toggle)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state, react-hook-form, faunadb

I have the following use case:

*A user wants to toggle whether a profile is active or not.*

**Configuration:**
Next.js,
Fauna DB,
react-hook-form

I use useState to change the state on the toggle, and react-hook-forms to send other values to my Fauna database and the state from the toggle. I would like the toggle to have the state from the database, and when the user toggles it followed by a press on the submit button, I would like to change the state in the database.

I cannot seem to send the right state back to the database when I'm toggling it.

Main component:

```js
export default function Component() {
 const [status, setStatus] = useState(
    userData?.profileStatus ? userData.profileStatus : false
  );

const defaultValues = {
    profileStatus: status ? userData?.profileStatus : false
  };

const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({ defaultValues });

  const handleUpdateUser = async (data) => {

    const {
      profileStatus
    } = data;
    try {
      await fetch('/api/updateProfile', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          profileStatus
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      alert(`submitted data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleUpdateUser)}>
      <Toggle status={status} setStatus={setStatus} />
      <button type="submit">
        Save
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Toggle component:

```js
import { Switch } from '@headlessui/react';

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');
}

export default function Toggle({status , setStatus}) {

  return (
    <Switch.Group as="div" className="flex items-center justify-between">
      <span className="flex-grow flex flex-col">
        <Switch.Label
          as="span"
          className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
          passive
        >
          Profilstatus
        </Switch.Label>
        <Switch.Description as="span" className="text-sm text-gray-500 w-44">
          Her sætter du om din profil skal være aktiv eller inaktiv.
        </Switch.Description>
      </span>
      <Switch
        checked={status}
        onChange={setStatus}
        className={classNames(
          status ? 'bg-blue-600' : 'bg-gray-200',
          'relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500'
        )}
      >
        <span
          aria-hidden="true"
          className={classNames(
            status ? 'translate-x-5' : 'translate-x-0',
            'pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200'
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Switch.Group>
  );
}
```

updateProfile.js

```js
import { updateProfileInfo } from '@/utils/Fauna';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (!session) return res.status(401);

  const userId = session.user.id;
  if (req.method !== 'PUT') {
    return res.status(405).json({ msg: 'Method not allowed' });
  }

  const {
    profileStatus,
    image,
    about,
    preferences,
    socialmedia
   } = req.body;
  try {
    const updated = await updateProfileInfo(
      userId,
      profileStatus,
      image,
      about,
      preferences,
      socialmedia
    );
    return res.status(200).json(updated);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Something went wrong.' });
  }
  res.end();
};
```

Fauna.js

```js
const updateProfileInfo = async (
  userId,
  profileStatus,
  image,
  about,
  preferences,
  socialmedia
) => {
  return await faunaClient.query(
    q.Update(q.Ref(q.Collection('users'), userId), {
      data: {
        profileStatus,
        image,
        about,
        preferences,
        socialmedia
      }
    })
  );
};

module.exports = {
  updateProfileInfo

}
```

Can you guys see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your `handleUpdateUser` function called? I see it defined but never invoked.

Comment: Where is the code that performs the Fauna query to update the profile?

Comment: Hi both, 

Thanks for spending your time helping. I've updated the original description to contain your asking information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I made a small sandbox to demonstrate how you could implement your use case using `react-hook-form`.

The reason it isn't working is, that you never update `react-hook-form`'s internal state when toggling the switch, you only update your `useState`. So when you call `handleUpdateUser` the data that is passed as the argument is the initial data you set via `defaultValues`.

Actually there is no need to use `useState` here, as you could just use `react-hook-form`'s internal form state. For this to work you have to use the  `<Controller />` component `react-hook-form` provides as the `<Switch />` component from Headless UI `@headlessui/react` is an external controlled component which doesn't expose a `ref` prop for an actual `<input />` element (`<Switch />` uses a `<button />` instead of an `<input />` element). You can find more info [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#IntegratingwithUIlibraries).

This way to you can also make your `<Toggle />` more generic for a reuse by providing a `value` and `onChange` prop instead of `status` and `setStatus`. But of course you could also use these names still. The `<Controller />` will provide a `value` and `onChange` prop on the `field` object which i spread on the `<Toggle />` component.

In your example it isn't clear how your `<Component />` component will receive the initial `userData`. I assumed you'd make an api request and so i put it in a `useEffect`. To update the form state after the api call finished you have to use the `reset` method `react-hook-form` provides. If you only render `<Component />` when the `userData` is already loaded you can omit this step and just pass the result to the `defaultValues` to `useForm`.

I mocked the api calls with a simple Promise, but you should get the idea.

**Component.js**

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Toggle from "./Toggle";

// Server Mock
let databaseState = {
  profileStatus: true
};

const getUserData = () => Promise.resolve(databaseState);
const updateUserData = (newState) => {
  databaseState = newState;

  return Promise.resolve(newState);
};

function Component() {
  const { control, reset, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { profileStatus: false }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const result = await getUserData();

      reset(result);
    };

    loadData();
  }, [reset]);

  const handleUpdateUser = async (data) => {
    try {
      const result = await updateUserData(data);

      console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleUpdateUser)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="profileStatus"
          render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => <Toggle {...field} />}
        />
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Toggle.js**

```js
import { Switch } from "@headlessui/react";

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function Toggle({ value, onChange }) {
  return (
    <Switch.Group as="div" className="flex items-center justify-between">
      <span className="flex-grow flex flex-col">
        <Switch.Label
          as="span"
          className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
          passive
        >
          Profilstatus
        </Switch.Label>
        <Switch.Description as="span" className="text-sm text-gray-500 w-44">
          Her sætter du om din profil skal være aktiv eller inaktiv.
        </Switch.Description>
      </span>
      <Switch
        checked={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        className={classNames(
          value ? "bg-blue-600" : "bg-gray-200",
          "relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
        )}
      >
        <span
          aria-hidden="true"
          className={classNames(
            value ? "translate-x-5" : "translate-x-0",
            "pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200"
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Switch.Group>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit inspiring-moon-0lqhdg]